# Wordpress - Changing Text of <a> tag in cosmica theme

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a blogging site using wordpress cosmica theme.

In that theme, there is a slider on which various other elements are shown such as header element and few  tag.Currently the  tag text is "Read More" & "Buy Now".I want to change the text for  tag, however I dont see the option of customizing it. I want to know, how can I change the text for the  tags. Please refer to screenshot for more clarity.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird that there wasn't an option to change the button text... You'll have to do it manually. (Be carefull changing anything in the code as it might damage your wordpress installation)

Go to **appearance > editor**
then on the right side open `functions.php`

Do a quick search using `ctrl + f` for the word 'read more'.

Then change this:

`<?php _e('Read More', 'cosmica'); ?>`

To anything you want:

`<?php _e('Anything you want', 'cosmica'); ?>`

Then simply hit save,

Note:
You have to do this for every slide